# How to decode Windows-1254 file to a readable format in Python

Tags: python, decode, windows-1252

I have a file that contains a Windows-1254 encoded data and I want to decode it to a readable format with python but I have no success so far.

I tried this code but I am getting an erorr:

```
file = open('file_name', 'rb')
content_of_file = file.read()
file.close()
decoded_data = content_of_file.decode('cp1254') # here I am trying to decode that file
print(decoded_data)
```

**This is the error that I get:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/encodings/cp1254.py", line 15, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 658: character maps to

The way that I now that this file was encoded in Windows-1254 is by using the `chardet.detect(data)['encoding']` so keep that in mind.

**Does someone knows how can I decode taht data in a way I could understand it?**

> this is the file content if someone need it.
> b'c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s3\x03\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x01\x03\x03\x03\t\x02\x02\t\x03\x03\x03\t\x02\x02\td\x02\x00d\x00\x00l\x00\x00}\x01\x00d\x02\x00d\x00\x00l\x01\x00}\x02\x00t\x02\x00\x83\x00\x00}\x03\x00d\x03\x00}\x00\x00t\x03\x00|\x03\x00\x83\x01\x00d\x04\x00k\x03\x00rZ\x00d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\xd0\x02|\x03\x00d\x06\x00\x19d\x07\x00k\x03\x00ry\x00d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00t\x05\x00|\x03\x00d\x08\x00\x19\x83\x01\x00d\t\x00Ad\n\x00k\x03\x00r\xa2\x00d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d\x0b\x00d\x0c\x00!d\x00\x00d\x00\x00d\x02\x00\x85\x03\x00\x19j\x06\x00d\r\x00\x83\x01\x00s\xd4\x00d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00t\x07\x00d\x0e\x00\x83\x01\x00\x19j\x08\x00\x83\x00\x00\x0co\x07\x01|\x03\x00t\x07\x00d\x0e\x00\x83\x01\x00\x19d\x0f\x00j\t\x00d\x10\x00\x83\x01\x00k\x02\x00s\x19\x01d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00|\x01\x00j\n\x00d\x11\x00d\x04\x00\x83\x02\x00d\x06\x00\x14d\x11\x00\x17\x19j\x0b\x00d\x12\x00\x83\x01\x00d\x13\x00k\x03\x00rU\x01d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00t\x05\x00|\x03\x00d\x14\x00\x19\x83\x01\x00t\x05\x00|\x03\x00d\x15\x00\x19\x83\x01\x00Ad\x16\x00k\x03\x00s\x89\x01|\x03\x00d\x14\x00\x19d\x17\x00k\x03\x00r\x98\x01d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d\x18\x00\x19d\x19\x00j\t\x00d\x1a\x00\x83\x01\x00k\x03\x00r\xc0\x01d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d\x1b\x00\x19d\x1c\x00j\x0c\x00d\x1c\x00d\x1d\x00\x83\x02\x00k\x03\x00r\xeb\x01d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00t\r\x00d\x1e\x00d\x0b\x00\x83\x02\x00\x19t\x0e\x00d\x11\x00\x83\x01\x00d\x1f\x00\x17j\t\x00d\x10\x00\x83\x01\x00k\x03\x00r&\x02d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d \x00d!\x00!j\x0c\x00d"\x00d\x00\x00d\x00\x00d\x02\x00\x85\x03\x00\x19d\x1c\x00\x83\x02\x00d\x1c\x00k\x03\x00ra\x02d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d!\x00\x19t\x0f\x00i\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00j\x10\x00d\x0b\x00\x19k\x03\x00r\x8d\x02d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d#\x00\x19t\x0e\x00d\x06\x00\x83\x01\x00k\x03\x00r\xb2\x02d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x03\x00d$\x00\x19d%\x00k\x07\x00r\xd1\x02d&\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00|\x02\x00j\x01\x00|\x03\x00d'\x00\x19\x83\x01\x00j\x11\x00\x83\x00\x00d(\x00k\x03\x00r\xff\x02d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00t\x05\x00|\x03\x00d)\x00\x19\x83\x01\x00t\x07\x00d*\x00\x83\x01\x00k\x03\x00r*\x03d\x05\x00GHt\x04\x00\x83\x00\x00\x01n\x00\x00d+\x00GHd\x00\x00S(,\x00\x00\x00Ns\x1a\x00\x00\x00#Import random,md5 modulesi\xff\xff\xff\xffs\x14\x00\x00\x00#Start checking flagi\x12\x00\x00\x00s\x05\x00\x00\x00NO!!!i\x00\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00Mi\x01\x00\x00\x00i\xff\x00\x00\x00i\xaa\x00\x00\x00i\x02\x00\x00\x00i\x04\x00\x00\x00t\x02\x00\x00\x00HCs\x10\x00\x00\x00([] > {}) << -~1t\x02\x00\x00\x007bt\x03\x00\x00\x00hexi\x05\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00base64s\x05\x00\x00\x00ZA==\ni\x06\x00\x00\x00i\x07\x00\x00\x00i\x1a\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00ii\x08\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00nt\x05\x00\x00\x00rot13i\t\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00st\x04\x00\x00\x001010t\x01\x00\x00\x00fi\x0b\x00\x00\x00i\r\x00\x00\x00t\x02\x00\x00\x00ypi\x0e\x00\x00\x00i\x0f\x00\x00\x00t\x08\x00\x00\x00dddddddds\x06\x00\x00\x00NO!!!!i\x10\x00\x00\x00t \x00\x00\x00eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3i\x11\x00\x00\x00sM\x00\x00\x00~(~(~((((~({}<[])<<({}<[]))<<({}<[]))<<({}<[]))<<({}<[]))<<({}<[]))<<({}<[]))s\n\x00\x00\x00Bazinga!!!(\x12\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00randomt\x03\x00\x00\x00md5t\t\x00\x00\x00raw_inputt\x03\x00\x00\x00lent\x04\x00\x00\x00quitt\x03\x00\x00\x00ordt\n\x00\x00\x00startswitht\x04\x00\x00\x00evalt\x07\x00\x00\x00isalphat\x06\x00\x00\x00decodet\x07\x00\x00\x00randintt\x06\x00\x00\x00encodet\x07\x00\x00\x00replacet\x03\x00\x00\x00intt\x03\x00\x00\x00strt\x04\x00\x00\x00typet\x08\x00\x00\x00__name__t\t\x00\x00\x00hexdigest(\x04\x00\x00\x00t\x07\x00\x00\x00commentR\x0f\x00\x00\x00R\x10\x00\x00\x00t\x03\x00\x00\x00ans(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00sA\x00\x00\x00XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXt\x0c\x00\x00\x00get_the_flag\x0b\x00\x00\x00sl\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x12\x01\x0c\x01\x0c\x01\t\x02\x06\x01\x12\x01\x05\x01\n\x02\x10\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x1a\x01\x05\x01\n\x01#\x01\x05\x01\n\x016\x01\x05\x01\n\x01-\x01\x05\x01\n\x014\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x19\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x1c\x01\x05\x01\n\x01,\x01\x05\x01\n\x01,\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x1d\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x16\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x10\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x1f\x01\x05\x01\n\x01\x1c\x01\x05\x01\n\x01'

Comment: There's a lot of null bytes there for cp1254.  Are you sure that's the right encoding? How was the file encoded?

Comment: for my understanding its a "bad windows-1254 (Turkish, based on ISO-8859-9) encoding". I do not know how the file was encoded this is part of my assignment I needed to figer out what encoding type it was and now decode it.